# Why is a variable available outside it's code block?

Tags: javascript

I ran into this little gem 5 minutes ago. I have been playing with JavaScript for a long while now and, since I follow best practice, I've never met such case, nor understand why it works while I supposed it shouldn't :

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
   // ... something
}
console.log("i=", i);
```

**will** output `10`

How is `i` available outside the `for` block? I always thought the declaration part was to have a local variable only available within that block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I always thought the declaration part was to have a local variable only available within that block.

Nope, not in JavaScript.

JavaScript loops (and most blocks in general) have no block scoping (until then next version rolls out with `let`.)

There are only two places where JavaScript does block scope at the moment and that's `with` clauses (you shouldn't use those anyway) and `catch` clauses.

Instead, JavaScript relies mostly on function scoping - variables declared in a function are local to that function.

Comment: This answer is more or less saying the same as the suggested "duplicate" question. (Sorry about the repetition. Blame Google for not being smart enough when querying all sorts of things on the subject.)

Comment: @YanickRochon for future reference, this is referred to as "Hoisting" the variable. See [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) on `var`

Comment: @jasonscript, first time I see this term :) (Not native english.)

Comment: @YanickRochon Hoisting pretty much means "lifting". So the var declarations are lifted to the top of the function block automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's equivalent to:

```
var i=0;
while (i<10){
   // ... something
   i++;
}
```

In fact, loops do not even create their own scope at all:

```
var x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
  x++;
  var i = 5;
}
i; // 5
```

Comment: Interesting. Like I said, I've never wrote such... crappy code, so I would have never guessed without actually trying it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I suppose so; I'll just remove the spec reference then :P

Comment: @Doorknob these are the droids you're looking for http://es5.github.io/#x10.2 :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That still doesn't really list what creates a new scope and what doesn't though

Comment: @Doorknob no it doesn't and the list is a lot more exhaustive than one might think, it's not just `with`, `catch`, FunctionExpression, FunctionDeclaration and global scope (although those are the major ones). Those are the ones if you avoid eval (direct or indirect) scope for the most part (not to mention host object extensions). That's the reason for the usual incorrect but good enough "JS only has only function scope" :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the declaration of `i` is outside the code block. In any case, Javascript doesn't have a block-level scope. Variables are either global, or within the scope of a function.

Answer (score 0):

`i` will be available below where you have defined it, unless you close off the scope, like:

```
(function(){
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  }
})();
console.log(i); // undefined
```

This should not matter though, because as long as you are using other loops below you can use the same increment variable *(with the exception of nested loops)*, which will overwrite the other one. A problem could arise when you have a loop where you forget to use the keyword `var`. Always use `var` would be my recommendation. A closure is not usually necessary.

In a nested loop you can use the same increment variables again like:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  for(var n=2; n<44; n+=2){
  }
}
// feel free to use `i` and `n` again
```

Or loops like this:

```
var ar1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
for(var i=0,l=ar1.length,n=0; i<l; i++,n+=2){
}
// feel free to use `i`, `l`, and `n` again
```

Personally, I find it a best practice to reserve vars `i`, `n`, `c`, and `q` for counters and `l` for length. Then I don't use them elsewhere, besides in loops.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not address the question directly. The question is not about finding ways to isolate `i`, but why it is visible outside the `for` block.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there's no "block scope", but "function scope". It means that, as soon as your variables are defined inside a function, they'll remain alive from the point that they're declared until the end of that function, whether inside or out side a block.

Here is the test case for js variable scope (from [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X), sections 3.2.1 Scoping and functions)

Test case:

```
function outer(){
  var a = 1;
  function inner(){ /* does nothing */ }
  var b = 2;
  if (a == 1) {
    var c = 3;
  }
}
outer();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 'In javascript, there's no "block scope"' that statement is incorrect though.

Comment: Here, I mean block scope <---> {}, but not (). With (), of course, we can create a self-executing function like what PHPglue said above. This, in turn, create a closure. Do you want to mention that case ?

Comment: `try{throw 5}catch(x){/* x is defined in this scope and is equal to 5*/}`